# How to fix the piping to a shell in Dockerfile which results in "cannot execute binary file" error

Tags: linux, bash, docker

I am trying to Dockerize one of the application and this is what my docker file looks like.

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04 as base

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y curl
RUN curl -sL https://deb.flexiwan.com/setup | bash - apt-get install -y flexiwan-router

RUN touch /etc/fwagent/token.txt
```

When I run this, I see the following error:

```
Step 3/4 : RUN curl -sL https://deb.flexiwan.com/setup | bash - apt-get install -y flexiwan-router
  ---> Running in a0e8ae9f9370
/usr/bin/apt-get: /usr/bin/apt-get: cannot execute binary file
The command '/bin/sh -c curl -sL https://deb.flexiwan.com/setup | bash - apt-get install -y flexiwan-router' returned a non-zero code: 126
```

I tried to change my shell to bash and also quoted around the command but nothing seems to work. Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: What is `bash - apt-get install ...` supposed to do? That is, what do you *think* this code should accomplish?

Comment: (and once you've answered that -- err, *why* do you think the code should do that thing? If there's documentation from the Flexiwan folks you're trying to follow, it wouldn't hurt to quote that documentation).

Comment: Its supposed to install the package from the repository we just setup using the script downloaded from curl.

Comment: To be much more specific: Why do you think `bash - apt-get` is correct, all on one line?

Comment: Ya, my bad.....

Answer (score 1):

You have to split one line of your Dockerfile such as:

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04 as base

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y curl 
RUN curl -sL https://deb.flexiwan.com/setup | bash - 
RUN apt-get install -y flexiwan-router
RUN touch /etc/fwagent/token.txt
```